# "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert", when running a chainlink node and try to deploy TestnetConsumer contract?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, evm, chainlink

The scenario is when deploying a [ATestnetConsumer.sol](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thodges-gh/8df9420393fb29b216d1832e037f2eff/raw/350addafcd19e984cdd4465921fbcbe7ce8500d4/ATestnetConsumer.sol) on mathchain via Remix, following the official tutorial to run a node on mathchain, which is a EVM-compatitable public chain. And I finish deploying the Oracle contract and LINKToken contract, and running the node on mathchain successfully, but when trying to deploy a TestnetConsumer contract, it shows that:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32603, "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert", "data": "" }
```

Anybody know why?

The TestnetConsumer contract is list as below:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.4/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/Ownable.sol";

contract ATestnetConsumer is ChainlinkClient, Ownable {
  uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 1 * LINK;

  uint256 public currentPrice;
  int256 public changeDay;
  bytes32 public lastMarket;

  event RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    uint256 indexed price
  );

  event RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    int256 indexed change
  );

  event RequestEthereumLastMarket(
    bytes32 indexed requestId,
    bytes32 indexed market
  );

  constructor() public Ownable() {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
  }

  function requestEthereumPrice(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumPrice.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "USD");
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumChange(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumChange.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    req.add("path", "RAW.ETH.USD.CHANGEPCTDAY");
    req.addInt("times", 1000000000);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function requestEthereumLastMarket(address _oracle, string _jobId)
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(stringToBytes32(_jobId), this, this.fulfillEthereumLastMarket.selector);
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    string[] memory path = new string[](4);
    path[0] = "RAW";
    path[1] = "ETH";
    path[2] = "USD";
    path[3] = "LASTMARKET";
    req.addStringArray("path", path);
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, ORACLE_PAYMENT);
  }

  function fulfillEthereumPrice(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumPriceFulfilled(_requestId, _price);
    currentPrice = _price;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumChange(bytes32 _requestId, int256 _change)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumChangeFulfilled(_requestId, _change);
    changeDay = _change;
  }

  function fulfillEthereumLastMarket(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _market)
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    emit RequestEthereumLastMarket(_requestId, _market);
    lastMarket = _market;
  }

  function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
    return chainlinkTokenAddress();
  }

  function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
  }

  function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(_requestId, _payment, _callbackFunctionId, _expiration);
  }

  function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
      return 0x0;
    }

    assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
      result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is located at the constructor:

```js
constructor() public Ownable() {
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
}
```

When you run a node on a public-chain, and deploy a totally new LINKToken contract as the way to `transferAndCall` the service provided by your own node, do remember to replace the line:  `setPublicChainlinkToken()` to:

```js
    // set the Oracle contract address
    setChainlinkOracle(YOUR_ORACLE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS); 
    // set LINKToken contract address
    setChainlinkToken(YOUR_LINKTOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
```

Then you should be good to go. And remember that you should deposit some LINK token before invoking the function to get service from your Chainlink node!